# Oracle: Select Min with Where Clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, where-clause, min

I am trying to run the following statement against an Oracle database and getting a missing expression message. I suspect the issue is because the SELECTs for MINOVERLAP and MAXOVERLAP don't recognise OVERLAPS as a table, but I am now stuck. I am running this query within a tool called Qlikview, so don't have the benefit of creating temporary tables, etc. It needs to be done as a single query if at possible.

```
SELECT UCR, TR,
SELECT(MIN(OVERLAP_START_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MINOVERLAP
SELECT(MAX(OVERLAP_END_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MAXOVERLAP
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT REF_WORKFLOW.UCR,
    REF_WORKFLOW.TR,
    OVERLAP_START_DT,
    OVERLAP_END_DT
  FROM CDW.REF_WORKFLOW
  JOIN CDW.REF_WEL_PREV_TR_OVERLAP
  ON REF_WEL_PREV_TR_OVERLAP.WORKFLOW_SID=REF_WORKFLOW.WORKFLOW_SID
  JOIN CDW.REF_TRANS_PART_LINE
  ON REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.UCR       =REF_WORKFLOW.UCR
  AND REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.TR       =REF_WORKFLOW.TR
  AND REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.BUREAU_ID='SY'
  JOIN CDW.REF_WORKFLOW_EVENT
  ON REF_WORKFLOW_EVENT.TRANS_PART_LINE_SID            =REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.TRANS_PART_LINE_SID
  WHERE REF_WORKFLOW.BUREAU_ID                         = 'SY'
  AND REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.PARTICIPANT_TRANS_ROLE_CODE IN('AGREEMENT PARTY','LEAD')
  AND REF_WEL_PREV_TR_OVERLAP.OVERLAP_ELAPSED_DURATION >0
  AND REF_WORKFLOW_EVENT.WORKFLOW_EVENT_DT            >= TO_DATE('24/04/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
  ) OVERLAPS;
```

Comment: Parentheses around the subqueries results in a "missing right parenthesis" message which seems strange as all parentheses are closed off. I believe it does support common table expressions, we are using WITH...AS expressions successfully elsewhere. Not sure what you mean by the query being "unbalanced" and we can't use analytics, sadly.

Comment: You have the right number, but in the wrong place; `SELECT(MIN...` should be `(SELECT MIN...`. So you need to move that opening parenthesis for both subqueries, rather than adding another set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as missing a comma, your subqueries need to be enclosed properly in parentheses; and the ones you already have are unbalanced. Or rather, in the wrong place; you currently start those with `SELECT(MIN...` where it should be `(SELECT MIN...`. Move the opening parenthesis to before the subquery's `SELECT`, rather than adding another set.

So you would need:

```
SELECT UCR, TR,
(SELECT MIN(OVERLAP_START_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MINOVERLAP,
(SELECT MAX(OVERLAP_END_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MAXOVERLAP
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT ...
  ) OVERLAPS;
```

But as you suspect, your OVERLAPS inline view is not in scope for those subqueries. You could use a CTE instead, if your tool supports that (some are fussy):

```
WITH OVERLAPS AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ...
)
SELECT UCR, TR,
(SELECT MIN(OVERLAP_START_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MINOVERLAP,
(SELECT MAX(OVERLAP_END_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MAXOVERLAP
FROM OVERLAPS;
```

Your logic is still flawed though. I think you're trying to do correlation, but your conditions will always be true; for example this:

```
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
```

... is comparing the value in each row with itself, so will always evaluate to true (unless the value is null).

You might find it simpler to use the analytic version of min/max with a windowing clause, with a CTE or inline view:

```
SELECT UCR, TR,
  MIN(OVERLAP_START_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY UCR ORDER BY TR
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MINOVERLAP,
  MAX(OVERLAP_END_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY UCR ORDER BY TR
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MAXOVERLAP
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT ...
  ) OVERLAPS;
```

Largely untested because we don't have any data or expected results, but that will hopefully give you some pointers.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/5705) showing a CTE with subqueries, with incorrect results because of the correlation issue mentioned above; and the analytic approach. Using a few made-up rows of data, obviously.

If you can't use analytic functions for some reason, you can fix the correlation issue by aliasing the CTE within the subquery:

```
WITH OVERLAPS (UCR, TR, OVERLAP_START_DT, OVERLAP_END_DT) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ...
)
SELECT UCR, TR,
  (SELECT MIN(O2.OVERLAP_START_DT)
  FROM OVERLAPS O2
  WHERE O2.UCR = OVERLAPS.UCR
  AND O2.TR <= OVERLAPS.TR) AS MINOVERLAP,
  (SELECT MAX(O2.OVERLAP_END_DT)
  FROM OVERLAPS O2
  WHERE O2.UCR = OVERLAPS.UCR
  AND O2.TR <= OVERLAPS.TR) AS MAXOVERLAP
FROM OVERLAPS;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/5713).

Comment: Regarding the missing braces in the in-line view, *you beat me to it!*

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I have used the last of your suggestions and it appears to be working against my data. I'll do some checking, but it's looking quite promising.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma on the 5th line:

```
SELECT UCR, TR,
SELECT(MIN(OVERLAP_START_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MINOVERLAP, -- <<< here
SELECT(MAX(OVERLAP_END_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS
WHERE OVERLAPS.UCR=UCR
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MAXOVERLAP
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT REF_WORKFLOW.UCR,
    REF_WORKFLOW.TR,
    OVERLAP_START_DT,
    OVERLAP_END_DT
  FROM CDW.REF_WORKFLOW
  JOIN CDW.REF_WEL_PREV_TR_OVERLAP
  ON REF_WEL_PREV_TR_OVERLAP.WORKFLOW_SID=REF_WORKFLOW.WORKFLOW_SID
  JOIN CDW.REF_TRANS_PART_LINE
  ON REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.UCR       =REF_WORKFLOW.UCR
  AND REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.TR       =REF_WORKFLOW.TR
  AND REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.BUREAU_ID='SY'
  JOIN CDW.REF_WORKFLOW_EVENT
  ON REF_WORKFLOW_EVENT.TRANS_PART_LINE_SID            =REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.TRANS_PART_LINE_SID
  WHERE REF_WORKFLOW.BUREAU_ID                         = 'SY'
  AND REF_TRANS_PART_LINE.PARTICIPANT_TRANS_ROLE_CODE IN('AGREEMENT PARTY','LEAD')
  AND REF_WEL_PREV_TR_OVERLAP.OVERLAP_ELAPSED_DURATION >0
  AND REF_WORKFLOW_EVENT.WORKFLOW_EVENT_DT            >= TO_DATE('24/04/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
  ) OVERLAPS;
```

Answer (score 0):

> getting a missing expression message

You are using **in-line view**, but you have missing **comma**

Here:

```
AND OVERLAPS.TR  <=TR) AS MINOVERLAP
SELECT(MAX(OVERLAP_END_DT)
```

Why not use the **WITH** clause a.k.a **sub-query factoring** feature. For the MIN and MAX calculations, use the with clause and then use it in the **filter predicate**.

Comment: You're right, but I'm still getting the message, sadly.

Comment: You need to put all the in-line views within braces. `SELECT UCR, TR,
(SELECT MIN(OVERLAP_START_DT)
FROM OVERLAPS...`